# Kubernetes Pod YAML - command and args

Tags: kubernetes

I've noticed a few different ways of setting commands and arguments for a Pod.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: busy
  name: busy
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - echo hello;sleep 3600
    image: busybox
    name: busy1
  - command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args:
    - -c
    - echo hello;sleep 3600
    image: busybox
    name: busy2
```

The above containers execute the same command/args, but one doesn't have `command` specified. Instead, the command is within `args`. Why is it possible to do this?

I also know that there is shell vs. exec form, and that exec form executes the command in the main process. What is the benefit of using either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Command`: Controls the actual command run by the container image.

`Args`: Controls the arguments passed to the command.

`Kubernetes` allows you to override both the image’s default `command` (docker `Entrypoint`) and `args` (docker `Cmd`) with the `Command` and `Args` fields of `Container` in the `pod spec`.

As mentioned [here](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/containers/#how-docker-handles-command-and-arguments):

1. If you do not supply a `Command` or `Args` for a container, the defaults defined by the image will be used.
2. If you supply a `Command` but no `Args` for a container, only the supplied Command will be used; the image’s default arguments are ignored.
3. If you supply only `Args`, the image’s default command will be used with the arguments you supply.
4. If you supply a `Command` and `Args`, the image’s defaults will be ignored and the values you supply will be used

By separating the `command` and `args` fields, `K8s` allows for more flexibility in defining the `command` to be executed inside the container. You can define a custom `command` and args` combination that is specific to your use case, and it can be different from the default command specified by the container image.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That makes sense. The key I was missing is the overriding of the docker image's defaults - I hadn't made that connection. Thanks!

Comment: One important detail here is that Kubernetes `command:` overrides a Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`, and `args:` matches `CMD`.  There's a reasonably common pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script to do some initial setup and `CMD` being a full command; if the image does this, and you need to override it, it's better to override `args:` only (and provide an actual command there).